# DropColumn conditionally in a migration

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework-5, database-migration

I want to perform a column dropping in my `Up` migration. I am using EF 5.

```
DropColumn("dbo.MyObjects", "AttributeId");
```

The issue is that in some way part of database instances do not have that column (long story how). I am thinking of dropping it with `Sql` and searching in `sys.columns`, or wrapping DropColumn in `try ... catch`.

But maybe there is some known way to do it with Entity Framework migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was also a default constraint on my column, so ended up with the following:

```cs
public override void Up()
{
    Sql(@"IF EXISTS(
     SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns c
     INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
     WHERE c.name = 'AttributeId' AND t.name = 'MyObjects')
     BEGIN
       DECLARE @AttributeIdDefConstraint nvarchar(128)
       SELECT @AttributeIdDefConstraint = name
       FROM sys.default_constraints
       WHERE parent_object_id = object_id(N'dbo.MyObjects')
         AND col_name(parent_object_id, parent_column_id) = 'AttributeId';
       IF @AttributeIdDefConstraint IS NOT NULL
       BEGIN
     EXECUTE('ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyObjects] DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @AttributeIdDefConstraint)
       END
       ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyObjects] DROP COLUMN [AttributeId]
     END");
}
```

Hope that will save one's time.

Comment: Decided to post the solution here so that somebody can reuse.